# AJAX JQUERY RELATED:- How to call ajax on a ajax loaded page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Assume I'm calling search through AJAX. Now I want to call another AJAX  on the page that will be loaded by AJAX and can be edited.

```
<input type="button" id=sb value="Search Contacts" />

<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search contacts" id="s1" style="display:none" />

<input type="text" id="b1" value="<?php echo $username ; ?>" style="display:none;float:left" />
```

I am using AJAX to call a php file. Now, I further want to call AJAX on the data loaded through AJAX. Is it possible?

**Or**

Can I call an jquery (AJAX) containing page through AJAX? Will that work?

I am creating search box and its displaying result from database through AJAX which gives me in the form of table. Now, I want to convert that table into live table which on click can be edited and data can be stored.

I know how to create live table but don't know how to call search as well as live table at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Jquery delegate for binding events to live elements

```
$('body').delegate('#yourtableid','click /*or watever you want*/',function(){
//do stuff here (editing)
});
```

Comment: even ajax can be called within function or javascript can be called?

Comment: @user1171499 ..i dont understand..please be more specific

Comment: CAn i call an ajax or jquery containing page through ajax @ubercooluk

Comment: I want to create  table in which one row which is input type and is hidden and the other containing same data as previous  row is uneditable. This table will be first called through ajax and then on clicking on table its hidden input type row should be visible and the other one should hide on mouseup data should be updated to database.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have something basically like this structure and jQuery 1.7+

```
<div id="resultContainer">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <!-- editable data -->
      <span>data</span>

      <!-- that turns into like this on click -->
      <form>
        <input type="text" value="data">
        <input type="submit" value="save">
```

On the parent page, you need to attach "delegated handlers", which are event handlers placed on parent elements that execute for present or future child elements.

And so, assuming that we have a container div id'ed "resultContainer" in which you dump the live data, we attach it handlers:

```
//attach a delegated submit handler on resultContainer for forms
$('#resultContainer').on('submit','form',function(event){
    //do what you want when an item is edited
    //"this" inside here is the DOM element form, which fired the submit
    //prevent the default submit action using event.preventDefault()
    //$(this).serialize() turns the form data into a serialized query string
});
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP page of my application in this live search with pagination i am applied

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//====================================================================================================================
//============================================first call when page load=============================================
    function ajaxCall(n)
    {
        //alert("display ajacCall ");
        //alert("page no ::"+n);

        var ajaxRequest;
        try
        {
                ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        catch (e)
        {
                try
                {
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } 
                catch (e) 
                {
                        try
                        {
                                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                         } 
                    catch (e)
                    {
                            alert("Your browser broke!");
                            return false;
                    }
            }
        }
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState==4)
                {
                        //alert("Response :: "+ajaxRequest.responseText);
                        document.getElementById("displayButton").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
                        if(n!=0)
                        {
                            disp_Record(n);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            disp_Record(0);
                        }
                }
        }

        var query="ajaxhendler.php?msg=select";
        //alert("Request ::" +query);
        ajaxRequest.open("POST",query,true);
        ajaxRequest.send();
    }
//================================================Display Recodr to button Press================================================
//================================================Display Record to Static Button===============================================
    function disp_Record(n)
    {   
        //alert("display record function");
        var ajaxRequest;
        try
        {
                ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        catch (e)
        {
                try
                {
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } 
                catch (e) 
                {
                        try
                        {
                                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        } 
                    catch (e)
                    {
                            alert("Your browser broke!");
                            return false;
                    }
            }
        }
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState==4)
                {
                        //alert("Response :: "+ajaxRequest.responseText);
                        document.getElementById("displayRecord").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
                }
        }

        //alert("txt::"+ txt)
        var query="ajaxhendler.php?msg=selectRecordNo&no_of_record="+n;
        //alert("Request ::" +query);
        ajaxRequest.open("POST",query,true);
        ajaxRequest.send();
    }

//==============================================For Live search==============================================================
//===========================================For live search Display Button=================================================
    function callSearch(n,text)
    {   
        //alert("call Search First Function");
        var ajaxRequest;
        try
        {
                ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        catch (e)
        {
                try
                {
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } 
                catch (e) 
                {
                        try
                        {
                                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        } 
                    catch (e)
                    {
                            alert("Your browser broke!");
                            return false;
                    }
            }
        }
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState==4)
                {
                        //alert("Response :: "+ajaxRequest.responseText);
                        document.getElementById("displayButton").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
                        if(n!=0)
                        {
                            disp_Record_live(n,text);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            disp_Record_live(0,text);
                        }
                }
        }
        var txt=document.getElementById("txtsearch").value;
        //alert("txt::"+ txt)
        var query="ajaxhendler.php?msg=selectRecord&txt="+txt;
        //alert("Request ::" +query);
        ajaxRequest.open("POST",query,true);
        ajaxRequest.send();
    }

//====================================================================================================================
function disp_Record_live(n,text)
    {   
        //alert("Display Record live Second Function");
        var ajaxRequest;
        try
        {
                ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        catch (e)
        {
                try
                {
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } 
                catch (e) 
                {
                        try
                        {
                                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        } 
                    catch (e)
                    {
                            alert("Your browser broke!");
                            return false;
                    }
            }
        }
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState==4)
                {
                        //alert("Response :: "+ajaxRequest.responseText);
                        document.getElementById("displayRecord").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
                }
        }

        var txt=document.getElementById("txtsearch").value;
        //alert("txt::"+ txt)
            var query="ajaxhendler.php?msg=select_Record_No_live&no_of_record_live="+n+"&findR="+txt;
        //alert("Request ::" +query);
        ajaxRequest.open("POST",query,true);
        ajaxRequest.send();
    }

</script>


</head>

<body onLoad="<?php if($_GET['txt']=="")
                    {
                        echo "ajaxCall(";
                        $n=0; if($_GET['page']!=null)
                            { 
                                echo $_GET['page']; 
                            }
                            else
                            { 
                                echo $n;
                            }
                        echo ")";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "callSearch(";
                        echo $_GET['page'].",'".$_GET['txt']."')";
                    } ?>" onUnload="msg()" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <form>
 <table width="100%">


  <tr bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                                <td  colspan="5"> 
                                       <font color="#CC6666">Search Record By Name</font><input type="text" name="txtsearch" id="txtsearch" value="<?php echo $_GET['txt'];?>" onKeyUp="callSearch(<?php
                                       $n=0; 
                                       if($_GET['page']!=null)
                                       { 
                                        echo $_GET['page'].",'".$_GET['txt']."'";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        { echo $n;}

                                        ?> )"/>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">  
                                        <a href="insert.php">Insert Record</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%">
                             <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div id="displayRecord"></div>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div id="displayButton">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                </table>

        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my Handlerpage.php

```
<?php
        $page_name = "http://localhost/desk.php";
        $msg=$_GET['msg'];
if($msg=='select')
        {

                load_pages($_GET['page']);
        }
        if($msg=="selectRecord")
        {
                live_search_pages();
        }
        if($msg=="selectRecordNo")
        {
            $n=$_GET['no_of_record'];
            disp_Record($n);
        }
        if($msg=="select_Record_No_live")
        {
            $n=$_GET['no_of_record_live'];
            live_search($n,$t);

        }

//==================================================================pages============================================
//=====================================================Static button================================================
function load_pages($page)
{
        $cn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("per_info",$cn);
        $query="SELECT count(*) 'TR' from p_info";
        $rs = mysql_query($query);
        $rec = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
        $n=$rec['TR'];
        if($n>0)
        {
        $pages=ceil($n/3);

        $i=0;

        echo "<table align=\"center\"><tr><td align=\"right\" bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Pages : </td><td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#666666\">";
        while($i<$pages)
        {
                echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"".($i+1).""; echo "\" onclick=\"disp_Record(".($i*3).")\" />";
                $i=$i+1;
        }
        echo "</td></tr></table>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No Record Found";
        }
}
//============================================Selected record Display By Button========================================
//==========================================Display Record for static Record==========================================
        function disp_Record($btn)
        {
                $cn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                mysql_select_db("per_info",$cn);

                //$btn=1;

                    $query="SELECT u.p_id 'ID', u.p_name 'NAME', u.p_add 'ADDRESS', l1.loc_name 'CITY', l2.loc_name
                        'STATE',u.p_gen
                        'GENDER', u.p_photo 'PIC', u.p_phone 'PH'
                        FROM p_info u, tbl_state l1, tbl_state l2
                        WHERE u.p_city = l1.loc_id
                        AND l2.loc_id = l1.loc_parent ORDER BY u.p_id desc LIMIT ".$btn.", 3";

                    $rs = mysql_query($query);
                    echo "<table width=\"100%\" frame=\"hsides\" >
                            <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Name</font></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Address</font></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">City</font></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">State</font></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Gender</font></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Photo</font></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Phone No</font></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"></th>";
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
                {

                    echo "<tr>
                                <td>".$row['NAME']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['ADDRESS']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['CITY']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['STATE']."</td>
                                <td>";if($row['GENDER']=="1")
                                        {
                                                echo "Male";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                                echo "Female";
                                        }
                                echo "</td>
                                <td>
                                    <img src=\"".$row['PIC']."\" alt=\"Pulpit rock\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" />      
                                </td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['PH']."</td>
                                <td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Edit\" onclick=\"getid(".$row['ID'].",".$btn.",'')\"/></td>
                                <td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" onclick=\"callDelete(".$row['ID'].",".$btn.",'')\"/></td>
                          </tr>";

                }


        }

//==========================================================Live search By Button=====================================

function live_search_pages()
{
        $txt=$_GET['txt'];
        $cn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("per_info",$cn);
        $query="SELECT count(*) 'TR' from p_info where p_name like '".$txt."%'";
        $rs = mysql_query($query);

        $rec = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
        $n=$rec['TR'];
        if($n>0)
        {
            $pages=ceil($n/3);

            $i=0;

            echo "<table align=\"center\"><tr><td align=\"right\" bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Pages : </td><td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#666666\">";
            while($i<$pages)
            {
                    echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"".($i+1).""; echo "\" onclick=\"disp_Record_live(".($i*3).")\" />";
                    $i=$i+1;
            }
            echo "<td></tr></table>";
            }
        else
        {
            echo "No record Found";
        }
}
//================================================================Live search==========================================
        function live_search($btn,$text)
        {
                $txt=$_GET['findR'];
                $text=$_GET['text'];
                $cn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                mysql_select_db("per_info",$cn);



                if($text==null)
                {

                $query="SELECT u.p_id 'ID', u.p_name 'NAME', u.p_add 'ADDRESS', l1.loc_name 'CITY', l2.loc_name 'STATE', u.p_gen 
                        'GENDER', u.p_photo 'PIC', u.p_phone 'PH'
                        FROM p_info u, tbl_state l1, tbl_state l2
                        WHERE u.p_city = l1.loc_id
                        AND l2.loc_id = l1.loc_parent
                        AND u.p_name LIKE '".$txt."%' ORDER BY u.p_id desc LIMIT ".$btn.", 3";
                }
                else
                {

                    $query="SELECT u.p_id 'ID', u.p_name 'NAME', u.p_add 'ADDRESS', l1.loc_name 'CITY', l2.loc_name 'STATE',u.p_gen
                        'GENDER', u.p_photo 'PIC', u.p_phone 'PH'
                        FROM p_info u, tbl_state l1, tbl_state l2
                        WHERE u.p_city = l1.loc_id
                        AND l2.loc_id = l1.loc_parent
                        AND u.p_name LIKE '".$text."%' ORDER BY u.p_id desc LIMIT ".$btn.", 3";
                }
                if($rs=mysql_query($query))
                {
                    echo "<table width=\"100%\" frame=\"hsides\">
                                <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Name</font></th>
                                    <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Address</font></th>
                                    <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">City</font></th>
                                    <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">State</font></th>
                                    <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Gender</font></th>
                                    <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Photo</font></th>
                                    <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Phone No</font></th>
                                    <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"></th>
                                    <th bgcolor=\"#666666\"></th>";
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
                    {
                            echo "<tr>
                                        <td>".$row['NAME']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['ADDRESS']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['CITY']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['STATE']."</td>
                                        <td>";if($row['GENDER']=="1")
                                                {
                                                        echo "Male";
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                        echo "Female";
                                                }
                                        echo "</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <img src=\"".$row['PIC']."\" alt=\"Pulpit rock\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" />      
                                        </td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$row['PH']."</td>
                                        <td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Edit\" onclick=\"getid(".$row['ID'].",".$btn.",'".$txt."')\"/></td>
                                        <td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" onclick=\"callDelete(".$row['ID'].",".$btn.",'".$txt."')\"/></td>
                                  </tr>";


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "error";
                }
        }
?>
```

I hope that it will helps you

Comment: I am using Jquery so please give solution considering that

Comment: ok i will try this functionality in jquery then after inform you soon