# javascript select city from selected country value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

i have db of countries from here http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3018309.htm
with 239 countries, every country have value. After i have selected another country in option, how can i update zone list with zones from new value?

```
$country_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY name ASC");
$zone_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zone WHERE country_id = '" . (int)$country_id . "' AND status = '1'");

<select name="country_id">
          <option value=""><?php echo '$text_select;' ?></option>
          <?php while ($country=mysql_fetch_array($country_query)) { ?>
          <?php if ($country['country_id'] == $country_id) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: what javascript code do you have so far?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML with the country and zone drop down list?

Comment: sorry, i don't have js yet, but i understood that i need it, to can select just needed items from db after country will be selected, by value with country ID.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242974/ajax-jquery-related-how-to-call-ajax-on-a-ajax-loaded-page/11243250#11243250 please visit this url it helps  you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time by default counties list will be loaded..
to load zones use this

```
<select name="country" id='country'>
          <option value=""><?php echo '$text_select;' ?></option>
          <?php while ($country=mysql_fetch_array($country_query)) { ?>
          <?php if ($country['country_id'] == $country_id) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Here you need to call ajax when country changed

**JQuery :**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#country').change(function(){

        $.post('ajax/getZones', 
                   {Country : $('#country').val()}, 
                   function(response){
                     //prepare the zones html code
                     //write that code to zone dropdown 
                  }, 'json');

    });

});
</script>
```

Here **'ajax/getZones'** refers **getZones** is the method in **ajax** controller

write the getZones query in **getZones**(ajax) 
get the Country id with **$_POST['Country']** in ajax controller

try implement ajax controller everything work fine..